# Update table records with another table information any example?

Tags: mysql

Hi I needed to update a lot of rows in mysql with information from another table.
any example please

Comment: do you need to update columns in table1 from another table2 and there any column is common in both table on which basis you are going to update in table1

Comment: I've just gave you an example, but believe me whan I tell you your question is really too vague. What do you have to update? Which are the conditions?

Comment: just got the solutions thanks for all

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get an answer to this, however please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for future reference when asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mysql manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE `Table A`,`Table B`
SET `Table A`.`text`=concat_ws('',`Table A`.`text`,`Table B`.`B-num`," from ",`Table B`.`date`,'/')
WHERE `Table A`.`A-num` = `Table B`.`A-num`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE tableA SET columnA = (SELECT columnB FROM tableB) WHERE id=1
```

You can make the query as extended as you want. Make sure you only select 1 field in the subquery

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_field = NULL
WHERE your_id IN
  (SELECT id FROM other_table
   WHERE name = 'josh')
```